# Outlook sends mail twice in a row

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, digital-signature

I have a problem with Outlook 2010. When I try to send a mail with digital signature, Outlook sends the mail twice in a row. Both mails look identical and both have the smime.p7s attachment.

When I don't use digital signature, the mail is sent only once. I'm signing mails using my ID card. The certificates for signing and encryption appear in windows certificate store and then I can select them using Outlooks Trust Center-> e-mail security.

Comment: I would check if there are any macros doing stuff with mail messages. If there are any, buggy code might interfere with mail sending even if it should not have something to do with certs.

Comment: @TFM How would I do that? I'm not very experienced with Outlook. I'm using default installation of Outlook right now. This behavior persisted over several OS reinstalls, so I don't think that it's something that I set up.